# How to unload a table with a field with ROWID datatype?

Tags: db2, zos

I have to unload a table which contains field with ROWID datatype. I could not unload the table through QMF as it is not supporting this data typr. Is there any other way to unload the table?

Answer (score 1):

In DB2, ROWID serves more of an internal function to the RDMS than what is allowed by end users.  This is intentional.  See link:

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.doc.sqlref/xf7c63.htm

However, if you do not need the ROWID properties (use the data for read-only purposes) then it may be possible to mimic unloading / loading of this table.

You can use the EXPORT / IMPORT commands to do the unloading / loading functions, which should support ROWID, but if it does not, then you can achieve the same functionality by converting the unsupported datatype ROWID into a supported datatype.  The only thing is, that once you do this, you will not be able to convert the data back into this datatype.  In other words, all the properties of ROWID will now be a regular INTEGER field.

```
select INTEGER(ROWID)  as int-rowid
     , col2
     , coln
  from table
 order by 1
```

Then you can execute the EXPORT / IMPORT command to unload / load the data.

Warning: Once you get rid of the ROWID properties, you cannot gain this back.  In other words, INSERTS to this table will NOT automatically increment the ROWID field.